# Run Oracle Forms as standalone without browser

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to run Oracle Forms standalone without any web-browser with java plugin.
Is there a way to call a compiled `.fmx` form directly via some java application or by calling the forms-JAR-files with some parameters?

CU, Arne

Comment: What version of Oracle Forms? Might be possible for 6i and below. Since Version 9i Oracle forms is web only requires some form of java applet when deployed in production.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: it is Oracle Forms 10g. We do not want to deploy through that webbrowser/applet-thing but as standalone application as in < 6i.
e.g. `java -jar oracleforms.jar myForm.fmx` and then we have some nice application running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inofficial contradiction: Yes, it's possible :-)

Oracle support says it is officially not supported, but you can use Web Start (again not supported by Oracle).

Support recommended this link: http://groundside.com/blog/JanCarlin.php?title=forms_and_java_web_start and our developers tried and succeeded. You can run it as local application without need of a web browser (looks like an applet without browser window around).

Update (2013-01-18): The blog seems to have moved/old entries vanished. See here at archive.org for original article: http://web.archive.org/web/20090303153527/http://groundside.com/blog/JanCarlin.php?title=forms_and_java_web_start&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1

Comment: I would need this solution for this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382272/running-oracle-forms-11g-outside-browser, but unfortunately the link isn't online anymore.

Comment: I updated the answer providing a link to archive.org with this article.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. Oracle forms 9i and above are web only releases. All the architecture needed to execute the fmx is now located within the Oracle Application Server.

The 2nd question from this link explains that Forms 9i (which 10g and later are built on) are web only releases

http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/forms/htdocs/formsservices9ifaq.html#UPGRADE