# Running Oracle Forms 11g outside browser

Tags: java, applet, oracleforms, appletviewer

We have an Oracle Forms 11g application which can be started via browser.
This leaves an empty browser window, since Forms opens its own window. However, if you close the empty browser window, the Forms window also get closed.

I like the fact that this kind of installation is a server installation and I can easily update it.

But I would prefer an icon (a shourtcut) on the desktop which just opens the Forms application without the browser window. I hoped to resolve this with the AppletViewer from the Java SDK.

However, when I start it with the URL of the start page I receive:

```
Warning: <embed> tag requires code attribute.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1129)
    at sun.applet.AppletViewer.parse(AppletViewer.java:1074)
    at sun.applet.Main.run(Main.java:156)
    at sun.applet.Main.main(Main.java:98)
```

Does anyone know how I can open the Forms application directly without the browser (and without a local installation of an app)?

PS: I know [Run Oracle Forms as standalone without browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361807/run-oracle-forms-as-standalone-without-browser), but it didn't help me, because the referenced link isn't online anymore.

**Update 1:** the link has been replaced, so this might be a solution I will try.
**Update 2:** we managed to run our Forms apps via Webstart like any other desktop application. Hurrah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the the Forms app open in the same browser window it was launched from, just put this in formsweb.cfg:

```
separateFrame=false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the solution using Javascript from [this](http://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-can-i-close-the-parent-browser-window-while-running-forms-on-the-web/) Blog post

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I can't understand how this will work, because if I manually close the browser window the form app gets killed. So if the form app closes the browser window I think it will kill itself. Anyway, I will try it.