# Is it possible to run Oracle Forms without applet

Tags: oracleforms

Is it possible oracle forms and report without applet? I have Oracle Forms and Report server 11gR2 with Weblogic server 10.3.6

Whenever I am try to run oracle forms and report on new machine,that ask me java plugin missing. Then it need to manually installation of that plugins.

Can I Oracle Forms and Report can run without applet(java plugin).

Comment: ````````````no````````````

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Oracle Forms as standalone without browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361807/run-oracle-forms-as-standalone-without-browser)